# Pasting correlation matrix into data editor

Tags: stata

I am computing some tests using the correlation between my variables. I have two main issues: I am using `svmat` to paste my matrix into the data editor. My matrix is originally 1 on the diagonal and all the correlations below this. When I use `svmat` it pastes a matrix that is symmetric which double counts my correlations. For example,

```
1 
0.5  1
0.3  0.5  1
```

Then using `svmat` I get something like

```
1    0.5   0.3
0.5  1     0.5
0.3  0.5   1
```

My code currently looks like:

```
matrix accum R = e1-e48
matrix R = corr(R)
matrix list R
clear
svmat R
```

I want to create a variable that is the sum of all the elements in the matrix. Is there an easy way to do this? I am doing it row by row at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show full and reproducible code, which is puzzling in a programming forum, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on posting good examples.

Backing up, your stated goal is the sum of a correlation matrix. Here I illustrate the use of `correlate`: the matrix is available immediately after that command. Note that the same technique applies to a correlation matrix obtained in any other way, such as in your code.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. corr headroom trunk length turn displacement
(obs=74)

             | headroom    trunk   length     turn displa~t
-------------+---------------------------------------------
    headroom |   1.0000
       trunk |   0.6620   1.0000
      length |   0.5163   0.7266   1.0000
        turn |   0.4245   0.6011   0.8643   1.0000
displacement |   0.4745   0.6086   0.8351   0.7768   1.0000

. ret li

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
                r(rho) =  .6620111289412028

matrices:
                  r(C) :  5 x 5

. mata : sum(st_matrix("r(C)"))
  17.97943754
```

So, pass the matrix to Mata to get the sum.

You can also pass it back.

As the sum of a matrix is just a constant, it need not be held in a Stata variable at all, which would be wasteful too. A scalar or local macro might be a suitable choice.

To show the last point: you can pass the sum back to Stata as a scalar:

```
. mata : st_numscalar("rsum", sum(st_matrix("r(C)")))

. di rsum
17.979438
```

Clearly you can also subtract the trace, equal to the number of variables, and halve the remainder. You could stay in Mata to do that, or do it in Stata.

In short, turning a correlation matrix into Stata data is an avoidable diversion for your purpose.